# Force csv-write-stream to always use doube-quotes (nodejs and electronjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using csv-write-stream to create and append data to CSV in nodejs and electronjs project.

Is there a way to force it to always use double-quotes around each entry of each row? So row would look something like this:

```
"2018-12-31","Bob","Jones"
```

My current working code (minus the double-quotes) is this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var csvWriter = require('csv-write-stream');
var writer = csvWriter({sendHeaders: false}); //Instantiate var
var csvFilename = "C:\some\path\myfile.csv";

// If CSV file does not exist, create it and add the headers
if (!fs.existsSync(csvFilename)) {
  writer = csvWriter({sendHeaders: false});
  writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(csvFilename));
  writer.write({
    header1: 'DATE',
    header2: 'LASTNAME',
    header3: 'FIRSTNAME'
  });
  writer.end();
} 

// Append some data to CSV the file    
writer = csvWriter({sendHeaders: false});
writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(csvFilename, {flags: 'a'}));
writer.write({
  header1: '2018-12-31',
  header2: 'Smith',
  header3: 'John'
});
writer.end();
```

This will output a row that looks like this, with no double-quotes:

```
2018-12-31,Bob,Jones
```

If you manually try to add the double-quotes to the data, then csv-write-stream actually wraps the data in double-quotes so you end up with this:

```
"""2018-12-31""","""Bob""","""Jones"""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code, it looks like this feature is not implemented. It tests each value for special characters (the separator, `\n`, `\r`, and `"`), and adds quotes only if those characters are in the stringified value. So either use another tool, or fork and submit a PR for the project :). There is an issue for the project that seems related: https://github.com/maxogden/csv-write-stream/issues/30

Comment: Yes that issue is exactly what I was looking for. So unfortunately csv-write-stream does NOT offer the option to force quotes around everything, as you said. :( Thxs